# How to redirect user from root node to it's child node in Magnolia CMS

Tags: java, spring-mvc, content-management-system, magnolia

My project is developed using Magnolia 5.3 and Blossom and is using Enterprise Edition - Standard version of magnolia.

I am new for Magnolia and this project.

This project is for different countries and in different languages.

It has the first page for the country and language listing. 
For ex. `www.localhost:8080` shows this country listing page.

When user clicks on any link of this page, then he is redirected to country home page with chosen language.

For Example:
Country C1 with language L1 has the URL: `www.localhost:8080/C1/L1`

And this shows the content of country root page i.e. C1

```
Each country has the same heirarchy in Magnolia CMS

C1 - Root Node of country C1
C1/XYZ1 - Page 1
C1/XYZ2 - Page 2

C2 - Root Node of country C2
C2/XYZ1 - Page 1
C2/XYZ2 - Page 2

and so on.
```

So if I want to access any root page of country then URL will be:

```
www.localhost:8080/C1/L1
```

And If I want to access any child page then URL will be:

```
www.localhost:8080/C1/L1/XYZ1
```

This is fine so far.

But now I want to remove or hide the country root page from the user. 
So If user manually type `www.localhost:8080/C1/L1` then

1. User should be warn with no page found or
2. User is redirected to page1 i.e. www.localhost:8080/C1/L1/XYZ1 and show page1 content.

I have tried with setting virtualURIMapping but this do not work.

I also tried to remove C1 page but I can not remove as this is the root page and it is not possible to remove root without it's children.

Please help and guide me, how can I do this?

Thanks,

Manoj

Comment: Can someone reply and guide me. I have stuck since 2 days on this.

Comment: First I want to be sure, is this possible?

Comment: Can someone give his opinion on my problem? Thanks

Comment: Can this problem be solved using URI mapping - https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS53/URI+mapping

I also tried this but not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Enterprise version, all you have to do is configure domain for your site to have it recognized properly and then Magnolia will hide root node automatically from all links.
If you are using Community edition, it's not possible as this feature is only in Enterprise.

However if you instead want to redirect to a subpage of the selected site (as it seems to now after your update of the question), you need to create a virtual URI mapping to do this.

There are many possible ways to create such mapping, one of them would be:
1) in AdminCentral, go to Configuration app and open `config:/modules/ui-admincentral/virtualURIMapping\default`
2) change `class` to `info.magnolia.multisite.MultiSiteRegexpVirtualURIMapping`
3) change `fromURI` to `\$`
4) change `toUri` to `redirect:/XYZ1\.html`
5) add property `site` and set it's value to `C1` (assuming your site in `WebDev/Sites` is called `C1`)

This will work only if you have your domains mapped properly in the site configuration. If you don't get it working on the first try, try to play with it, change the values, double check you have all config correctly. Try to maybe also look in the code of the mapping to make sure you understand how it work. And most importantly, check other VirtualURIMappings you have configured (you can see all in Config Info app).

Additional disclaimer: If you set virtual uri mapping incorrectly (specially since this one is regex based so it is super easy to "expand" it to react on all urls), it is possible to make your instance inaccessible. Make sure when you do this, you do so on your development instance and that you have backup and can go back. Only apply such change on production via importing previously created and tested mapping.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Hi, Jan Thanks for your reply. I am using the Enterprise version but I think, I was not able to explain my problem in proper way. So I updated my question in more detail. Please see this and reply me, how I can achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Jan, When will you be available to answer my question?

Comment: If you need help urgently and you are using Enterprise version, I suggest you open a support ticket at http://support.magnolia-cms.com.          Otherwise, yes I think it should be solvable with correct site and virtualUri configuration.

Comment: If this is still valid, I've added extra solution to your now updated question